# What is this bug found in a garden in Utah?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: Garden Bug]
Apologies for the poor quality of the photo.

I found this bug in a garden in Utah.  The body was flattish, with teal markings (lighter than it looks in the photo) with an interesting pattern of three dots along the back, and a pink cone projecting down to the rear.  It was about the size of my smallest fingernail.

From the searching I've done, the shape and the light "rim" on the outside of the shell look like a June Bug or a Stink Bug, but this one was not as green and the markings seem a lot more pronounced.

Is it a pest to be concerned about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the pattern of yellow spots it might be a Say Stink Bug. 
Check out [this list of common Utah stinkbugs](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3015&context=extension_curall)

[image: A Say Stink Bug]

The 12 - 17 mm size is consistent with OP's description and the fact that this insect is often found on ornamental shrubbery is consistent with finding it in a garden.

Comment: The picture on [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Say_Stink_Bug,_Chlorochroa_sayi;_Pentatomidae,_green_beetle,_pretty_bug_in_Yellowstone_National_Park.JPG) is an even closer match.  So much easier to find when you know what you are looking for.  Thanks.